# Ошибка в коде PHP для сайта

Tags: php, html

Помогите найти ошибку в коде пожалуйста. Сам ищу и никак найти не могу, в интернете тоже ничего не нашел по данной ошибке.

Выдает ошибку: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\OSPanel\domains\geekbrain.ru\index.php on line 12

Warning: mysqli_error() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in C:\OSPanel\domains\geekbrain.ru\index.php on line 12

Код:

```
    <?
   $link = mysqli_connect('localhost','mysql', 'mysql', 'gb') or die (mysqli_error($link));

   $page = $_GET['p'];

   if ($page = 2) {
    $name = $_POST ['name'];
    $link = $_POST ['link'];
    $info = $_POST ['info'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO news ( name, link, info) VALUES ( '$name', '$link', '$info')";
    $res = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
   }

?>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Блог</title>
    <meta charset="utf-t">
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li><a href="?p=1">Главная</a></li>
<li><a href="?p=2">Добавить</a></li>
</ul>

<?
   switch($page) {
case 2:
var_dump($_POST);
echo<<<text
<form method="post">
<input name= "name" placeholder="Название"><br>
<input name= "link" placeholder="Ссылка"><br>
<textarea name= "info" placeholder=""></textarea><br>
<input type='submit'>

</form>


text;
break;
default:
 $res = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT * FROM news')  or die (mysqli_error($link));

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
echo<<<text
<h2>{$row['name']}</h2>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{$row['link']}" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
text;
}
break;
}

?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Вы перебиваете свой линк. $link = $_POST ['link'];

Comment: А как мне сделать так, что бы я его не перебивал ?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php

Comment: Освойте оператор присваивания, что ли. Потом вопросы задавайте. Ну детский сад же. Вам указали на проблему, и все равно вы не желаете думать.

Comment: Сначала надо проверять, существует ли переменная GET и только потом присваивать

Answer (score 1):

По моему ошибка в переменной `$link`, потому возвращает `null` и поэтому в 12 строке ошибка. Проверь подключение в `$link`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавь проверку для форму добавления, на заполнение каждого поля

```
        if($_POST['name'] && $_POST['link'] && $_POST['info'])
        {
          $name = $_POST ['name'];
          $link = $_POST ['link'];
          $info = $_POST ['info'];

          $sql = "INSERT INTO news ( name, link, info) VALUES ( '$name', '$link', '$info')";
          $res = mysqli_query($link, $sql) or die (mysqli_error($link));
        }
```